# Python Not Installing on Windows 7 - The Installer Won't Even Appear

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

Trying to install python (version 3.7.1) on windows 7, and the installation file appears in my downloads folder. However, when I try to run the installation file, as admin, I get the prompt asking if I want to allow the program to make changes to my computer, which I allow, then the installer window *doesn't* appear. Nothing happens. I can't find a background program running, nothing. It's like the executable doesn't do anything. I'm really stuck.

If it helps I'm using a Windows 7 64-bit computer.

Comment: Are you installing the 32-bit version of Python or the 64-bit? Did you try downloading the install file again in case it did not fully download?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I also face that you are now facing.
The simplest ways to run a python software foundation in windows 7 is.
First completely update your windows 7. It take some minutes and some time Few hours. 
Once you install windows update.
The PYTHON software will run normally.

Accounting to my experience.

Answer (score 0):

i just install Anaconda which has python and packages, very convenient  : https://www.anaconda.com/download/